# How to assign a List to a Qstandarditem Python

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside2, qstandarditem

I have a model being built from a JSON. I have parsed the JSON and built the model with each object in the JSON Dict as a string. Everything worked great,  however I need one of the JSON objects to be a list. When I pass in the list just as I previously was with a string, it breaks my model. (Almost all entries are gone in my view) Is there a way for me to assign a list to a Qstandarditem?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I was dumb, I was never actually properly setting my data. I was just getting lucky with strings previously.